# Push notification with cordova (android) firebase

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, notifications

I am working with cordova10 android (9.1.0) and I cannot change the version because there are plugin works with this version but I have many problem one of them add android x and after solve them I got the following errors:
om\gae\scaffolder\plugin\FCMPlugin.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
^
symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceId
location: package com.google.firebase.iid
\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\gae\scaffolder\plugin\MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
^
symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceId
location: package com.google.firebase.iid
\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\gae\scaffolder\plugin\MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;
^
symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceIdService
location: package com.google.firebase.iid
\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\gae\scaffolder\plugin\MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
^
symbol: class FirebaseInstanceIdService
\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\gae\scaffolder\plugin\FCMPlugin.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
^
symbol: variable FirebaseInstanceId
\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\gae\scaffolder\plugin\FCMPlugin.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
callbackContext.success( FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() );
^
symbol: variable FirebaseInstanceId
\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\gae\scaffolder\plugin\MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java:15: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\gae\scaffolder\plugin\MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
^
symbol:   variable FirebaseInstanceId
location: class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
8 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s
22 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 20 up-to-date
Command failed with exit code 1: \platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b \platforms\android\build.gradle

here is package.json file:
`{ "name": "AutolinkCustomerApp", "version": "1.0.0", "private": true, "devDependencies": { "cordova-android": "^9.1.0", "cordova-ios": "4.2.0", "cordova-open": "^1.1.0", "cordova-pdf-generator": "^2.1.1", "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.5", "cordova-plugin-camera": "^5.0.3", "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.1.0", "cordova-plugin-fcm": "~2.1.2", "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2", "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^3.0.5", "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1", "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.0", "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0", "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0", "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.2.2", "cordova-windows": "4.4.2", "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^3.3.1", "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "~1.0.0" }, "cordova": { "platforms": [ "ios", "windows", "android" ], "plugins": { "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {}, "cordova-plugin-file": {}, "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {}, "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {}, "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {}, "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": { "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+" }, "cordova-pdf-generator": {}, "cordova-open": {}, "cordova-plugin-device": {}, "cordova-plugin-globalization": {}, "cordova-plugin-camera": { "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+" }, "cordova-support-google-services": {}, "cordova-plugin-fcm": {}, "cordova-plugin-firebase": {}, "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {} } } }`